# React state showing differing values from each dynamically generated input field component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I've been banging my head against my keyboard for the past 8 hours trying to figure out why each input field is showing different values for the same state.

Here is the code -

```
const BeaconSettingsCard = (props) => {
    const [settingsItems, setSettingsItems] = useState([]);

    const handleAddBeaconBtnOnClick = () => {
        const id = settingsItems.length;
        const newItem = (
            <InputItem
                id={id}
                key={id}
                type="InputField"
                title="Test Title"
                value="Test Value"
                onChange={(e) => handleBeaconIdInputFieldOnChange(e, id)}
            />
        );

        setSettingsItems((settingsItems) => [...settingsItems, newItem]);
    };

    const handleBeaconIdInputFieldOnChange = (e, id) => {
        console.log("settingsItems: ", settingsItems); // each input field shows a different settingsItems value ??
    };

    let cardHeaderButton = (
        <InputItem type="Button" width="150px" onClick={handleAddBeaconBtnOnClick}>
        Click to Add
        </InputItem>
    );

    return (
        <SettingsCard
            headerButton={cardHeaderButton}
            settingsItems={settingsItems}
        />
    );
};

export default BeaconSettingsCard;
```

When I log the "settingsItems" state in the onChange event for each input field, I get different values.

On the first dynamically generated inputfield, it logs settingsItems as `[]`. On the second, it logs `[{React Component}]`. On the third, it logs `[{React Component}, {React Component}]` and so forth.

These should all be logging the same state value! My friend who is a react wiz couldn't seem to figure this out either. Really hoping someone here can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this strange issue by converting the code from React hooks to a normal React component.

Not ideal, but works. Hopefully if someone runs into a strange issue like this, this solution will work for you too.